# Dynamically pass a map as the module attributes in terraform 12/13?

Tags: dynamic, foreach, module, terraform0.12+

### Question

How to you dynamically unpack a map into a module/resource attributes? I understand you can do [dynamic resource attributes blocks in terraform 12/13](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each?utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_BLOG&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE), but can you do it for all the attributes for the entire resource/module? For example:

```
module "this" {
  for_each = {
    att0 = "attr0"
    attr1 = "attr1"
    attr2 = "attr2"
  }

  each.key = each.value
}

# my hope is that this would do the equivalent of this code below

module "this" {
  attr0 = "attr0"
  attr1 = "attr1"
  attr2 = "attr2"
}
```

similiar to how you would do it in python with the splat kwargs into a function. e.g.

```py
# python3
kwargs = {"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
my_func(**kwargs)
```

other variations that I have tried:

```
module "this" {
  for_each = {
    att0 = "attr0"
    attr1 = "attr1"
    attr2 = "attr2"
  }
}
```

```
module "this" {
  {
    att0 = "attr0"
    attr1 = "attr1"
    attr2 = "attr2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Really nice question! Any luck so far?

Comment: @abyesilyurt it looks like terraform now supports [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) which can be use with [dynamic blocks](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/expressions?in=terraform/configuration-language&utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS).

Comment: bump on this! Trying to resolve same problem